# Does the following imply Lipschitz continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, vector-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{C}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^d$ be a function such that there is a $c > 0$ with 
$$
|\langle f(x) - f(y),x-y \rangle| \leq c \langle x-y,x-y \rangle
$$
for all $x, \; y \in \mathbb{C}^d$, where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ denotes the Hermitian product.

Does this imply that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: Do you mean $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^d$?

Comment: Note that examples of the form $f(x)=iax$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ show that there can be no bound on a Lipschitz constant for $f$ in terms of $c$.

Comment: @EricWofsey For d=1 this should be equivalent to Lipschitz with $L=c$. But I think I understand the idea: We rotate by 90 degree and multiply by a. This can never be a counterexample to Lipschitz though, because it is a linear map. It makes quite clear however, why it is a difficult question. Thanks!